# Shadow DOM styles encapsulation

Tags: css, google-chrome-extension, shadow-dom

I want to create a Chrome extension which will inject a widget into a web page.

My widget must have a consistent style when injected on any page. Afaik, the best way to achieve this is to use Shadow DOM.

It seems that by design Shadow DOM styles inherits from parent's page styles. One have to use `all:initial` CSS property for host element to prevent parent page's styles leak into the shadow DOM styles.

So, I have a sample code:

```
(function addWidget() {
  let rootEl = document.querySelector('body');
  let mount = document.createElement('div');
  rootEl.appendChild(mount);
  let shadowRoot = mount.attachShadow({mode: 'open'});
  shadowRoot.innerHTML = `
<style>
:host {
all: initial;
}

div {
position: fixed;
z-index: 2147483647;
border: 1px solid black;
padding: 30px;
font-size: 30px;
background: tomato;
top: 10px;
right: 10px;
}
</style>

  <div>Shadow DOM</div>
  `;
}());
```

If you open Chrome's dev tools and execute this code in the console, it'll work as expected on most websites. But on some websites (like reddit.com) the styles are still inherited from the parent page.

[image: reddit.com-vs-example.com]

What changes I have to make to be sure that the widget's styles will be consistent across all web pages.

Comment: Use `mount.style.cssText='all:initial'` instead of :host

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot!

Comment: @EugeneKarataev wOxxOm is statistically unlikely to turn his comment into an answer, could you please write a self-answer to this?

Comment: @Xan, sure, done.

Comment: @wOxxOm can you explain why this is necessary?

Comment: @Tom it's basically the same thing but higher CSS specificity. We can go higher with :host {all: initial !important} and even higher with mount.style.cssText='all:initial !important'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wOxxOm gave the correct answer:

> Use mount.style.cssText='all:initial' instead of :host